# Javascript nodeValue not accepting new variable

Tags: javascript, dom

Here's what I have:

I create this markup on the fly:

```
 <p id="amount"><span></span></p>
```

Now I need to fill up the span:

```
if (amount.firstChild.nodeType == 1) {
  amount.firstChild.nodeValue = text;

  alert(description.firstChild.nodeType); //this shows SPAN

}
```

amount is a variable created with getElementbyId and text is a variable that it works and shows just a figure.

Now, why isn't accepting text as a value? It renders and empty span... and text is working just fine....

thanks a lot fellas!

Comment: I doubt if the alert shows SPAN. It shows 1. Did you mean `nodeName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test for a nested text node in the span, and if there isn't one, create it.

```
var span = amount.firstChild
if (!span.firstChild)
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
else
    span.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
amount.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wdLGA/).

Answer (score 1):

```
amount.firstChild.innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. Otherwise, the text is parsed as HTML. If you fear browser compatibility issues, use `amount.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));`. If the `<span>` is not empty beforehand, prefix the snippet with `amount.firstChild.innerHTML = '';`